# iOS tableViewCell is not updating after reloading the tableview even after setting the properties properly

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell, reloaddata

I've been trying to figure out a problem in my code but no luck finding a solution.
I have a dropdown library which I'm using for dropdown the library is [ios Dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajNTq.png)
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajNTq.png): https://github.com/AssistoLab/DropDown here in this I've customised the the tableViewCell and I've added a radio button. But when I'm trying to reload it its not updating its state it still remains the same even after setting the state.

```
func updateCellBy(text: String, index: Int, isSelected: Bool) {
        self.index = index
        radioButton.isSelected = isSelected
        titleLabel.text = text
        checkboxButtonWidthConstraint.constant = 20
        radioButtonLeadingConstraint.constant = 15
    }
```

**But when I scroll this dropdown/tableview dropdown buttons state gets updated.** I'm still wodering whats wrong with this. Tested if the data coming in the above method is correct or not but that is correct.[DroppDown image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajNTq.png)
Note this dropdown is inside a collectionViewCell which is indeed inside a view.

```
dropDown.cellNib = UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil)
            dropDown.customCellConfiguration = { [self] (index: Index, item: String, cell: DropDownCell) -> Void in
                guard let cell = cell as? TableViewCell else { return }
                cell.updateCellBy(text: DropdownArrays.shared.getData()[index], index: index, isSelected: self.cellIndexes.contains(index))
                cell.delegate = self
            }
            dropDown.dataSource = DropdownArrays.shared.getData()
```

above is how I'm configuring that drop down. Its just a tableview with cells.

for reloadind the drop down I'm calling the below method

```
dropDown.reloadAllComponents()
```

which is indeed reloading the cell inside the DropDown library

```
Reloads all the cells.

    It should not be necessary in most cases because each change to
    `dataSource`, `textColor`, `textFont`, `selectionBackgroundColor`
    and `cellConfiguration` implicitly calls `reloadAllComponents()`.
    */
    public func reloadAllComponents() {
        DispatchQueue.executeOnMainThread {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
        }
    }
```

but the cell data is not updating.

Comment: How are you reloading the cell? From what you have shared, it seems that you are calling some method inside the custom cell class for updating the UI. That will not work as you need to tell the TableView to reload that cell. As you can see that the cell is updated on scrolling the tableview, you should reload the particular cell using relevant table view reload methods.

Comment: @PrasadParab the table view is not directly accesable as its a third party library. Table view is reloading fine I've cross verified it, after reload only the updateCell method will get called which is also workign, but the radio button inside the the cell is not uodated eeven after the tableview reload is called. But if I scroll the cell when it reappears it works fine. Updated the question you can check how I'm reloading.